# PHP Xpath following-siblings

Tags: php, xpath, domxpath

I'm trying to use xpath to get the contents of a table.

The table looks like this

```
<div>
<table>
<tr class="tableheader">
    <td> Stuff </td>
</tr>
<tr class="indent1">
     <td> Contents </td>
</tr>
<tr class="indent1">
     <td> Contents </td>
</tr>
<tr class="tableheader">
    <td> Stuff </td>
</tr>
<tr class="indent1">
     <td> Contents </td>
</tr>
<tr class="indent1">
     <td> Contents </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

I'm trying to pull the value of all tr[@class='indent1'] between table headers

this is what I have so far :

```
$elements = $xPath->query("div/table/tbody/tr[@class='tableheader']");

for ($i = 0; $i < $elements->length; $i++){
    print "Node: ".$elements->item($i)->nodeValue."\n";
    $siblings = $xPath->query("following-sibling::tr[@class='indent1']", $elements->item($i));
    foreach ($siblings as $sibling) {
        print "\tSibling: ".$sibling->nodeValue."\n";   
    }

}
```

The expected output is

```
Node: Stuff
   Sibling:  Contents
   Sibling:  Contents
Node: Stuff
   Sibling:  Contents
   Sibling:  Content
```

s

Instead it is printing ALL tr class="indent1s" for each one.

Thanks.

Comment: That it prints all `indent1` s for the first `tableheader` node is obvious as all following `indent1` s are siblings of this node. Can you please provide the exact output?

Comment: Right, well the exact output is broken, as you said its printing every indent1 because they are all siblings. 

What I'm trying to accomplish is the expected output above, which I can't seem to reach. I can't get it to print indent1 siblings between tableheader[1] and tableheader[2] and then tableheader[2] - [3] and so on..

hope that makes sense. thanks felix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

OK maybe this helps you. Just get every sibling and check the attributes with PHP:

```
foreach ($siblings as $sibling) {
    if (!is_null($sibling->attributes) 
        && $sibling->attributes->getNamedItem('class')->nodeValue == 'indent1') {
           break;
    }
    print "\tSibling: ".$sibling->nodeValue."\n";  
}
```

---

What is your goal in general? If you just want to print out the nodes, processing the structure with [SAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML) would be more appropriate and easier (SAX with PHP).

Or maybe [XSLT](http://www.php.net/manual/en/xsl.examples.php) but I cannot help you with that.

Comment: Well all this info will go into an array .. so this is a giant table: 

<tr class="header">
<td>Architecture Programs</td>
</tr>
<tr class="indent1">
   <td> - Architecture and Design </td>
</tr>
<tr class="indent1">
<td> - Building blueprint</td>
</tr>
<tr class="heading">
<td> Aviation </td>
</tr>
<tr class="indent1">
<td> Flying airplanes</td> 
</tr> 

The goal is to pull all program data for Architecture Programs and store them into an array  $program["Architecture Programs"] = @array("architecture and design", "building blueprints");

And then on to the next heading and values.

Comment: ... So thats why I'm just trying to get the <tr class="indent1"> between <tr class="header"> not ALL <tr class="indent1"> the problem is the are structured as siblings not children which makes it tougher